# SQL query much slower in MySql 8 than in MySql 5.6

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-8.0, mysql-5.6

I have a simple query:

```
select  count(*)
    from  ror
    where  rorsts not in ( 'RECD', 'CANC', 'CCNS', 'SDNY' )
      and  ( ( rorbcd = '00009310022487'
                      and  rorfid = 'VDR' )
              or  ( rorfid = 'VDR'
                      and  rorbcd in (
                        SELECT  pplbcd
                            from  ppl
                            where  pplfid = 'VDR'
                              and  pplscb6 = '00009310022487'
                              and  pplsflg = 'Y'
                              and  pplsku = '0332690-008'
                              and  ppldoc = '73'
                              and  pplsca9 = ''
                              and  pplven = '10112' ) ) 
           )
```

On a MySql 5.6 machine, it runs quite quick:

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        2 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

But on my MySql 8 server, it runs much slower:

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        2 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.90 sec)
```

I am mostly using default parameters for both servers (well, Amazon RDS defaults).  What parameter would cause this slowdown?  What configuration might help it run in MySql 8 with roughly the same speed as MySql 5.6.

As per many other places online, this is a bad SQL.  I could easily re-write it as an `exists`, I believe, which should be much more efficient.  My problem is that we are migrating from 5.6 to 8.0, and there is a good chance I will either miss a query, or not be able to fix one of the queries because of some weird requirement on my end.  I bet there is some parameter that I could tweak in my MySql 8 configuration to make this run in a way roughly comparable to 5.6.  That is what I am looking for.

More information:

1. Same Amazon RDS server setup, in terms of hardware
2. We just upgraded 5.6 to 5.7, then upgraded 5.7 to 8.0.  As much as possible, I kept with the default MySql parameters. I only purposely changed `lower_case_table_names = 1` and `max_connections=300`, to match 5.6 and our current requirements.
3. The PPL and ROR tables are extremely complex.  137 columns for PPL, and 144 columns for ROR.

For MySql 5.6 explanation, with an even simpler (and still faster) query, and some index information:

```
mysql> select version();
+------------+
| version()  |
+------------+
| 5.6.51-log |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> explain extended select count(*) from ror where rorsts not in ( 'RECD', 'CANC', 'CCNS', 'SDNY' )  and  ( ( rorbcd = '00009310022487' and rorfid = 'VDR'  ) or ( rorfid = 'VDR' and rorbcd in ( select pplbcd from ppl where pplfid = 'VDR' and pplscb6 = '00009310022487' and pplsflg = 'Y' and pplsku = '0332690-008' and ppldoc = '73' and pplsca9 = '' and pplven = '10112'  ) ) );
+----+--------------------+-------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type            | possible_keys                                                  | key          | key_len | ref        | rows | filtered | Extra                              |
+----+--------------------+-------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | ror   | ref             | ROR_RORBCDK,ROR_RORSTSK,ROR_RORBSTSK,ROR_RORSDT3K,ROR_RORGMOQK | ROR_RORGMOQK | 5       | const      |    1 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ppl   | unique_subquery | PPL_PPLBCDC,PPL_PPLDOCK,PPL_PPLVENC,PPL_PPLSKUC,PPL_PPLFID     | PPL_PPLBCDC  | 29      | func,const |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;                                                                                                                                                                                                                         +-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1003 | /* select#1 */ select count(0) AS `count(*)` from `celltreat`.`ror` where ((`celltreat`.`ror`.`RORSTS` not in ('RECD','CANC','CCNS','SDNY')) and (((`celltreat`.`ror`.`RORFID` = 'VDR') and (`celltreat`.`ror`.`RORBCD` = '00009310022487')) or ((`celltreat`.`ror`.`RORFID` = 'VDR') and <in_optimizer>(`celltreat`.`ror`.`RORBCD`,<exists>(<primary_index_lookup>(<cache>(`celltreat`.`ror`.`RORBCD`) in ppl on PPL_PPLBCDC where ((`celltreat`.`ppl`.`PPLVEN` = '10112') and (`celltreat`.`ppl`.`PPLSCA9` = '') and (`celltreat`.`ppl`.`PPLDOC` = '73') and (`celltreat`.`ppl`.`PPLSKU` = '0332690-008') and (`celltreat`.`ppl`.`PPLSFLG` = 'Y') and (`celltreat`.`ppl`.`PPLSCB6` = '00009310022487') and (`celltreat`.`ppl`.`PPLFID` = 'VDR') and (<cache>(`celltreat`.`ror`.`RORBCD`) = `celltreat`.`ppl`.`PPLBCD`)))))))) |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> select count(*) from ppl;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    95108 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> explain extended select count(*) from ppl;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ppl   | index | NULL          | PPL_PPLFID | 5       | NULL | 11194 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                             |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1003 | /* select#1 */ select count(0) AS `count(*)` from `celltreat`.`ppl` |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME,  index_name, COUNT(1) column_count FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'veeder' and table_name in ( 'ppl', 'ror' ) group by table_name, index_name order by table_name collate utf8_general_ci, index_name collate utf8_general_ci;
+------------+--------------+--------------+
| TABLE_NAME | index_name   | column_count |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
| ppl        | PPLKEY       |            1 |
| ppl        | PPL_PPLBCDC  |            2 |
| ppl        | PPL_PPLDOCK  |            3 |
| ppl        | PPL_PPLFID   |            1 |
| ppl        | PPL_PPLPONOC |            4 |
| ppl        | PPL_PPLSKUC  |            4 |
| ppl        | PPL_PPLVENC  |            5 |
| ror        | RORKEY       |            1 |
| ror        | ROR_RORBCDK  |            5 |
| ror        | ROR_RORBSTSK |            4 |
| ror        | ROR_RORCNSK  |            3 |
| ror        | ROR_RORCRDTK |            4 |
| ror        | ROR_RORCUIDK |            5 |
| ror        | ROR_RORDOCK  |            5 |
| ror        | ROR_RORGMOQK |            4 |
| ror        | ROR_RORPONOK |            6 |
| ror        | ROR_RORRORK  |            2 |
| ror        | ROR_RORSDT3K |            4 |
| ror        | ROR_RORSKUK  |            5 |
| ror        | ROR_RORSTSK  |            5 |
| ror        | ROR_RORUSTSK |            4 |
| ror        | ROR_RORVENK  |            7 |
| ror        | ROR_RORVSTSK |            4 |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
23 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And now the MySQL 8 explanation, with an even simpler (and still slower) query, and some index information:

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.23    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select count(*) from ror where rorsts not in ( 'RECD', 'CANC', 'CCNS', 'SDNY' )  and  ( ( rorbcd = '00009310022487' and rorfid = 'VDR'  ) or ( rorfid = 'VDR' and rorbcd in ( select pplbcd from ppl where pplfid = 'VDR' and pplscb6 = '00009310022487' and pplsflg = 'Y' and pplsku = '0332690-008' and ppldoc = '73' and pplsca9 = '' and pplven = '10112'  ) ) );
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys                                                  | key          | key_len | ref                     | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | ror   | NULL       | ref  | ROR_RORBCDK,ROR_RORSTSK,ROR_RORBSTSK,ROR_RORSDT3K,ROR_RORGMOQK | ROR_RORGMOQK | 5       | const                   | 185179 |    50.03 | Using where |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | ppl   | NULL       | ref  | PPL_PPLBCDC,PPL_PPLDOCK,PPL_PPLVENC,PPL_PPLSKUC,PPL_PPLFID     | PPL_PPLVENC  | 53      | const,const,const,const |      2 |     2.50 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.02 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1003 | /* select#1 */ select count(0) AS `count(*)` from `veeder`.`ror` where ((`veeder`.`ror`.`RORSTS` not in ('RECD','CANC','CCNS','SDNY')) and (((`veeder`.`ror`.`RORFID` = 'VDR') and (`veeder`.`ror`.`RORBCD` = '00009310022487')) or ((`veeder`.`ror`.`RORFID` = 'VDR') and <in_optimizer>(`veeder`.`ror`.`RORBCD`,`veeder`.`ror`.`RORBCD` in ( <materialize> (/* select#2 */ select `veeder`.`ppl`.`PPLBCD` from `veeder`.`ppl` where ((`veeder`.`ppl`.`PPLVEN` = '10112') and (`veeder`.`ppl`.`PPLSCA9` = '') and (`veeder`.`ppl`.`PPLDOC` = '73') and (`veeder`.`ppl`.`PPLSKU` = '0332690-008') and (`veeder`.`ppl`.`PPLSFLG` = 'Y') and (`veeder`.`ppl`.`PPLSCB6` = '00009310022487') and (`veeder`.`ppl`.`PPLFID` = 'VDR')) ), <primary_index_lookup>(`veeder`.`ror`.`RORBCD` in <temporary table> on <auto_distinct_key> where ((`veeder`.`ror`.`RORBCD` = `<materialized_subquery>`.`pplbcd`)))))))) |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> select count(*) from ppl;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    94657 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.49 sec)

mysql> explain select count(*) from ppl;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ppl   | NULL       | index | NULL          | PPL_PPLFID | 5       | NULL | 89284 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                          |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1003 | /* select#1 */ select count(0) AS `count(*)` from `veeder`.`ppl` |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME,  index_name, COUNT(1) column_count FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'veeder' and table_name in ( 'ppl', 'ror' ) group by table_name, index_name order by table_name collate utf8_general_ci, index_name collate utf8_general_ci;
+------------+--------------+--------------+
| TABLE_NAME | INDEX_NAME   | column_count |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
| ppl        | PPLKEY       |            1 |
| ppl        | PPL_PPLBCDC  |            2 |
| ppl        | PPL_PPLDOCK  |            3 |
| ppl        | PPL_PPLFID   |            1 |
| ppl        | PPL_PPLPONOC |            4 |
| ppl        | PPL_PPLSKUC  |            4 |
| ppl        | PPL_PPLVENC  |            5 |
| ror        | RORKEY       |            1 |
| ror        | ROR_RORBCDK  |            5 |
| ror        | ROR_RORBSTSK |            4 |
| ror        | ROR_RORCNSK  |            3 |
| ror        | ROR_RORCRDTK |            4 |
| ror        | ROR_RORCUIDK |            5 |
| ror        | ROR_RORDOCK  |            5 |
| ror        | ROR_RORGMOQK |            4 |
| ror        | ROR_RORPONOK |            6 |
| ror        | ROR_RORRORK  |            2 |
| ror        | ROR_RORSDT3K |            4 |
| ror        | ROR_RORSKUK  |            5 |
| ror        | ROR_RORSTSK  |            5 |
| ror        | ROR_RORUSTSK |            4 |
| ror        | ROR_RORVENK  |            7 |
| ror        | ROR_RORVSTSK |            4 |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
23 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I don't understand the warnings MySql 8 give, but maybe that is the key to finding the proper server setting.

The table definitions and indexes are kind of long, especially for both DBs, but I do have copies of them and they look virtually the same.  The biggest difference seems to be that in 5.6 I have some integer columns defined as "int(11)", and on 8.0, they are defined as "int".  In the "show create table" output, the indexes are the same.  Obviously, the "AUTO_INCREMENT" value is different, but this makes sense as the MySql 8 version is a week out of date.  Hopefully this is enough information.  When I do "describe ppl", "show indexes from ppl", "describe ror", and "show indexes from ror" on both DB servers, they are virtually the same except for the following:

1. As above, `int(11)` changed to `int`.
2. The "Cardinality" column changes.  It is less for the MySQL 8 version, probably because it is outdated
3. Obviously, 8.0 "show indexes" command shows more columns.  The "Visible" column is always "YES" and the "Expression" column is always "NULL".  Incidentally, INDEX_TYPE is "BTREE" for all indexes.

Because these are kind of big tables, the `show create table` and `describe <table>;show indexes from <table>` produce results too long for the body of a post.  So if you need more information, I will need to know what you don't need of what I have currently provided.  Thanks.

**Edit:**

- [MySql 5.6 create tables](https://pastebin.com/ake9x7u2)
- [MySql 8.0 creata tables](https://pastebin.com/6iumFe16)

**Edit after applying advice of @o-jones:**
The results below are after I ran `ANALYZE TABLE ror, ppl;`, but they match what was happening before I ran `ANALYZE TABLE ror, ppl;`.

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.23    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select count(*) from ror where rorsts not in ( 'RECD', 'CANC', 'CCNS', 'SDNY' )  and  ( ( rorbcd = '00009310022487' and rorfid = 'VDR'  ) or ( rorfid = 'VDR' and rorbcd in ( select pplbcd from ppl where pplfid = 'VDR' and '00009310022487' and pplsflg = 'Y' and pplsku = '0332690-008' and ppldoc = '73' and pplsca9 = '' and pplven = '10112'  ) ) );
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys                                                  | key          | key_len | ref                     | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | ror   | NULL       | ref  | ROR_RORBCDK,ROR_RORSTSK,ROR_RORBSTSK,ROR_RORSDT3K,ROR_RORGMOQK | ROR_RORGMOQK | 5       | const                   | 185179 |    50.03 | Using where |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | ppl   | NULL       | ref  | PPL_PPLBCDC,PPL_PPLDOCK,PPL_PPLVENC,PPL_PPLSKUC,PPL_PPLFID     | PPL_PPLVENC  | 53      | const,const,const,const |      2 |     2.50 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from ror where rorsts not in ( 'RECD', 'CANC', 'CCNS', 'SDNY' )  and  ( ( rorbcd = '00009310022487' and rorfid = 'VDR'  ) or ( rorfid = 'VDR' and rorbcd in ( select pplbcd from ppl where pplfid = 'VDR' and pplscb610022487' and pplsflg = 'Y' and pplsku = '0332690-008' and ppldoc = '73' and pplsca9 = '' and pplven = '10112'  ) ) );
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        2 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.80 sec)

mysql> explain select count(*) from ror USE INDEX(ROR_RORSTSK) where rorsts not in ( 'RECD', 'CANC', 'CCNS', 'SDNY' )  and  ( ( rorbcd = '00009310022487' and rorfid = 'VDR'  ) or ( rorfid = 'VDR' and rorbcd in ( select pplbcd from ppl wd = 'VDR' and pplscb6 = '00009310022487' and pplsflg = 'Y' and pplsku = '0332690-008' and ppldoc = '73' and pplsca9 = '' and pplven = '10112'  ) ) );
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys                                              | key         | key_len | ref                     | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | ror   | NULL       | ALL  | ROR_RORSTSK                                                | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                    | 370358 |    50.03 | Using where |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | ppl   | NULL       | ref  | PPL_PPLBCDC,PPL_PPLDOCK,PPL_PPLVENC,PPL_PPLSKUC,PPL_PPLFID | PPL_PPLVENC | 53      | const,const,const,const |      2 |     2.50 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from ror USE INDEX(ROR_RORSTSK) where rorsts not in ( 'RECD', 'CANC', 'CCNS', 'SDNY' )  and  ( ( rorbcd = '00009310022487' and rorfid = 'VDR'  ) or ( rorfid = 'VDR' and rorbcd in ( select pplbcd from ppl where ppl' and pplscb6 = '00009310022487' and pplsflg = 'Y' and pplsku = '0332690-008' and ppldoc = '73' and pplsca9 = '' and pplven = '10112'  ) ) );
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        2 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.25 sec)

mysql> explain select count(*) from ror where rorsts not in ( 'RECD', 'CANC', 'CCNS', 'SDNY' )  and  ( ( rorbcd = '00009310022487' and rorfid = 'VDR'  ) );+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys                                                  | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ror   | NULL       | range | ROR_RORBCDK,ROR_RORSTSK,ROR_RORBSTSK,ROR_RORSDT3K,ROR_RORGMOQK | ROR_RORBSTSK | 35      | NULL |   37 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from ror where rorsts not in ( 'RECD', 'CANC', 'CCNS', 'SDNY' )  and  ( ( rorbcd = '00009310022487' and rorfid = 'VDR'  ) );
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        2 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Incidentally, using the index hint is not an acceptable solution, in this case, because this is just one example SQL.  I always knew I could make this particular SQL more efficient.  My problem was that MySql 8 should be quicker, but is considerably slower, for the same SQL, so trying to figure out why.  I suspect the same thing would happen in MySql 5.7, but I have not tried that yet since I heard MySql 8 was the way to go.

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) then [edit] your question to give more information, including your table definitions and output from EXPLAIN in both versions of MySql.

Comment: I am just asking why the exact same SQL works differently.  I know I can improve this particular SQL in many ways.  Is there no configuration that impacts this?

Comment: And we cannot tell you why the same sql statement runs differently in the two mysql versions without seeing your data structure and the outputs of explain in both versions. Trust me, there is no magical setting in mysql v8 that suddently causes a query to run slower or faster!

Comment: The v8 query planner is quite different from the one in v5.6. Also, you may have changed storage engines, and it's even possible your indexes have changed.  It would be nice if the answer to your question were "set the framis variable to 42", but things are not so simple, sad to say.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  And `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for each version.

Comment: I already provided explains.  Create table too big for body.

Comment: When I tried to add either "show create table" or the list of indexes, it would not let me, said I was exceeding the maximum character count.  If someone could help me know what to get rid of, then I can reword my post and get rid of what I don't need, adding what I do need.

Comment: In case you are wondering, show create for 5.6 for both tables is 15,337, and the show create for 8.0 is 15,165.  Max length of a post for stackoverflow is 30,000, so that is why I have not posted those pieces of information.  if anyone has ideas on how to get around this, tell me.  If I just list the indexes, and get rid of some of my original question, I can probably give you that information.  Would that help?

Comment: @TonyB - To shrink size, remove (from `CREATE`) the columns that are not referenced.  Do show at least the `PRIMARY KEY` and the indexes that are likely to be used by the query.  I don't want to attempt rewriting the query and providing new indexes without seeing the Create.  Won't the Creates be identical between the versions?  If not please point out any differences; they could be important.  Also there are a number of post-it sites that will happily show large text files.

Comment: In the question, I mention that creates are virtually the same between the two databases.  I list out the minor differences there, things like `int(11)` becoming `int`.  Regardless, I can shrink the create later, if the current answer does not help me.  Thanks.

Comment: @TonyB For what you consider to be too much data to post, use pastebin.com to post your TEXT results and share the links with us.  Stripping any part of output will only result in misunderstanding what your computer has to deal with to arrive at the runtime conclusion for a query results.

Comment: Can you provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` on each version?  Those _may_ go into enough detail to see where the Optimizer "took the wrong path" in 8.0.

Comment: A nitpick -- don't prefix column names with table names; it makes the column names quite hard to read.  Then change `where  pplfid = 'VDR'` to `where  ppl.fid = 'VDR'` (adding dot) .

Comment: It seems that both sides of the `OR` have `rorfid = 'VDR'`.  Is that typical or just happenstance?

Comment: "func,const" baffles me.  Is there something special about special about `PPLBCD`?

Comment: Just a VARCHAR field, so no, nothing really special.

Answer (score 4):

Query plans for the primary (top-level) query -- the one using your `ror` table  --compared.

```
version  type   key        key_len  ref     rows Filtered Extra
 5.6.61 range  ROR_RORSTSK       6  NULL    3256    ----  Using index condition; Using where 
 8.0.23 ref    ROR_RORGMOQK      5  const 185179    50.03 Using where
```

For some reason the 8.0.23 query optimizer didn't choose the ROR_RORSTSK index to satisfy your query, but instead chose ROR_RORGMOQK. As a result the query couldn't use a range scan and had to filter (compare one-by-one) 185k rows rather than 3k rows. That is the visible difference between your two plans.

(5.6 EXPLAIN output doesn't include the Filtered column. You need EXPLAIN EXTENDED.)

You could try changing this line in your query

```
from ror
```

to

```
from ror USE INDEX(ROR_RORSTSK)
```

or

```
from ror IGNORE INDEX(ROR_RORGMOQK)
```

One of those might get v8 to use a similar query plan to v5.6.

You can probably figure out more with your knowledge of what columns are included in each index.

**EDIT**

Also try doing `ANALYZE TABLE ror, ppl;` especially if you just bulk-loaded the tables as part of your migration. If `ANALYZE` is unnecessary it won't hurt anything, and it may help the query planner choose the best plan.

Comment: So basically, for some reason, MySql 8 is not choosing the correct index.  I did not even notice it was finding a totally different index, which is weird.  I will experiment.

Comment: FYI: Actually, I figured out later that if I changed `explain` to `explain extended`, it would give me the filtered column for MySql 5.6.  I just did not bother updating my original post accordingly.

Comment: `ANALYZE` did nothing.  I think that happens during the upgrade process, but, like you said, no harm in trying.  It still chooses the wrong index, according to `explain`.  I will update the main post with this information, and dig into `ANALYZE` some to make sure I am not missing some special option.